# BlockHound Detects WebClient's ExchangeFunction's .next() Method As Blocking

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactor, reactor-netty

I am profiling my reactor application using `BlockHound`. I have a filter on my `ExchangeFunction`:

```
@Override
public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {
final ClientRequest.Builder builder = ClientRequest.from(request);
return Mono.defer(() -> next.exchange(builder.build())) //detects blocking call
    .transform(reactiveUtil::contextualize)
    .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel());
}
```

`BlockHound` detects a blocking call on the `next.exchange()`. Now since I am using `WebClient` with `Netty`, why would this call be non-blocking? Subscribing this on an `elastic` thread does not help.

Comment: What is the stacktrace shown by BlockHound?

Comment: @PhilClay 
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pandepra/8a5991b30c5385daffc283d2e33219d3/raw/5f07ff93a131dcdd62f53b4f7954a303f08ffc3b/gistfile1.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your gist, BlockHound is detecting `java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(..)` as blocking deep within the SSL handshake.

This problem has been reported in https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/939 and appears to be resolved in the latest releases.